# Qt MediaPlayer nothing played in linux. Windows only audio heard

Tags: c++, qt5

Ok have a slight problem while trying to create a very basic MediaPlayer simply want the video to start the second the application is started.

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>
#include <QMediaPlayer>
#include <QFileInfo>
#include <QDebug>


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
QApplication a(argc, argv);
MainWindow w;
QMediaPlayer media;
const QString file = "big_buck_bunny_480p_h264.mov";
QUrl url(QFileInfo(file).absoluteFilePath());
qDebug() << url << endl;
media.setMedia(url);
media.play();
w.show();

return a.exec();
}
```

Currently windows plays audio but fails to play video with the error

> no VideoWindowControl or videoRendererControl, unable to add output
>   node for video data

or in linux i get from the file path of file:///home/ion/Downloads/big_buck_bunny_1080p_h264.mov
I get

GStreamer; Unable to pause - "/home/ion/Qt_practice/file:/home/ion/Downloads/big_buck....

Error: "Invalid URI" - "/home/ion/Qt_practice/file:/home/ion/Downloads/big_buck....

From what i think it sounds like windows has problems with QMediaPlayer (is it because i'm not passing it to a QAbstractVideoSurface first ?). But anyway to my question what is the correct path if i want to point to the Downloads location on linux? Also why does windows only play audio is it a codec thing or ?

have even tried copying the file to the location the program is pointing to but even when it's in the directory I expect it still reports an Invalid URI. Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
    QMediaPlayer *player = new QMediaPlayer;
    player->setMedia(QUrl::fromLocalFile("big_buck_bunny_480p_h264.mov"));
    QVideoWidget *videoWidget = new QVideoWidget;
    w.setCentralWidget(videoWidget); // if w is a QMainWindow
    player->setVideoOutput(videoWidget);
    player->play();
```

Alternatively, if you want to know how to do it with QGraphicsVideoItem:

```
    QGraphicsView *graphicsView = new QGraphicsView(this);
    w.setCentralWidget(graphicsView); // w = QMainWindow
    QGraphicsScene *scene       = new QGraphicsScene(this);
    QMediaPlayer *player        = new QMediaPlayer(this);
    QGraphicsVideoItem *item    = new QGraphicsVideoItem;

    graphicsView->setScene(scene);
    player->setVideoOutput(item);

    graphicsView->scene()->addItem(item);
    player->setMedia(QUrl::fromLocalFile("big_buck_bunny_480p_h264.mov"));
    player->play();
```

Comment: Well cheers @Greenflow you leg end. Both works, quick question when should i use QGraphicsView instead of QVideoWidget ? Also where does QAbstractVideoSurface come into this is it just another method like QGraphicsView ? But yea legend helped alot, now it's time for me try try and implement it as an RTSP stream :P.

Comment: Quick answer: I don't know. I never had a problem yet where I had to choose. I personally would prefer QVideoWidget if possible. Seems easier. But there might be use cases, where it might be necessary to move video items in a QGraphicsScene around. QAbstractVideoSurface: I better shut up. Never used it myself. So no personal experience. :-)

Comment: Yea np @Greenflow just wanted to make sure that I wasn't doing something wrong by just using QVideoWidget too. So much more of a cleaner example. Cheers for the help, let you know how RTSP goes (well will create a post showing it's implementation anyway).

Comment: Btw just incase ur interested @Greenflow only difference i see so far is that GraphicsView always stays to the same size with that code, whereas VideoWidget fills the whole window.

Comment: With that code. A very simplified code. Just to show a minimal working example.  However, you can put the QGraphicsView easily into a layout.